# Fedora terminal: Extract single files from multiple folders into one folder?

Tags: fedora, file-moving

I have multiple folders with files. I would like all the files in one folder. How do i do this?
I tried mv *(extension) /path to current folder
but mv doesn't look into folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find . -name *.ext -type f -exec mv '{}' folder/. \;`

Comment: Appreciate it. Could you give an example for me please?

Comment: Just replace `ext` with the extension you wanted when you posted the question above and `folder` with the folder you wanted in the question above. I had to be general on both because you were general on both in the question.